# Как исправить ошибку при попытке подключения к серверу?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Последовательно прохожу вот этой гайд. Все что сделал деплою на heroku. Из-за того что heroku не поддерживает базу данных SQLite приходится использоваться postgresql. Новый проект создал с флагом "-d postgresql". При попытке зайти в приложение через http://localhost:3000 (естественно предварительно запустив сервер на пк) выдается следующая ошибка[image: ошибка]

Также прикладываю листинг сервера если он нужен.

```
PG::ConnectionBad (fe_sendauth: no password supplied
):

activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `initialize'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `new'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `connect'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:217:in `initialize'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `new'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:729:in `new_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:773:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:752:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:713:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:490:in `checkout'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:883:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:546:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (636.6ms)
```

Содержимое config/database.yml

```
default: &default

  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:

  <<: *default

  database: Testprogram_development

test:
  <<: *default

  database: Testprogram_test

production:

  <<: *default

  database: Testprogram_production

  username: Testprogram

  password: Testprogram
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#setting-the-application-home-page

Comment: Приведите содержимое вашего `config/database.yml`. И используемую ОС. Хотя последнее вряд ли понадобится.

Comment: Приложил содержимое config/database.yml

Comment: А как на счёт ОС?

Comment: Использую Windows 10

Comment: У-у-у... тогда это только первые из всех тех грабель, что вас ожидают. Но решение для конкретно этой беды: прописать реквизиты вашего сервера PostgreSQL в ваш `database.yml`, у вас это уже сделано для `production`. Единственный имеющийся ответ в целом верный.

Comment: Как там, заработало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No password supplied* означает, что вы не указали пароль для подключения к серверу.
Прежде чем использовать *@connection_parameters*, их надо заполнить.
Если в вашем гайде этого нет - выкиньте его.

Comment: Все дело в том что гайд не предусматривает использование базы данных postgresql, а мне необходимо ее использовать чтобы деплоить на heroku. Без нее все работает. Подскажите где я могу узнать что это за параметры и как их настраивать?

Comment: Я боюсь, что с вашим уровнем знания вопроса одним *подскажите* не отделаюсь :) Почитайте про подключение к postresql в интернете, про пароли, имя пользователя, как их создавать, как назначать права